# Issue with Importxml function in Google Sheet

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I need some help with the IMPORTXML function in Google Sheet.

I am trying to pull the LATEST PRICE from a Crypto Exchange: 
https://wazirx.com/exchange/BTC-INR

`=IMPORTXML("https://wazirx.com/exchange/BTC-INR","//span[ends-with(@class,'lbbppK')]")`

I have tried everything, but just cannot get this to work. I have pointed the class to specific string too, yet doesn't work.

Can anyone please help me retrieve the Latest Price?

*is it possible website is blocking the query?

Comment: The data is loaded dynamically using javascript, so GS can't handle it. You'll have to use a tool like selenium for that.

Comment: But... I want to update the Google Sheet with latest Price Regularly. Selenium wlll not suite for this purpose

Comment: tl;dr - It can't be done with GS (or Excel). You have to use python (or some other language) in which headless browsers are available.

Comment: Okay Thanks. Then there is no way for me to use GS.

Answer (score 0):

Should use a proper API service to get the data

You could do `=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")` to get BTC price in USD

then use Google's native function to convert it to INR

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDINR")`

All together, you could do

`=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDINR")`